# Diferença entre Immediate Child e First-Child?

Tags: html, css

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a diferença entre esses dois conceitos?

Pelo que eu entendi ambos significam a mesma coisa...mas realizando o teste abaixo, o texto ficou com a formatação do pseudo-seletor

```
div > p {
    font-family: Garamond;
}

p:first-child {
    font-family: cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repara no exemplo:

```css
div>p {
  font-family: Garamond;
  color: brown;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p:first-child {
  font-family: cursive;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Primeiro</p>
  <p>Segundo</p>
  <p>Terceiro</p>
  <section>
    <p>Neto um</p>
    <p>Neto dois</p>
    <nav>
      <span>Bisneto um</span>
      <p>Bisneto dois</p>
    </nav>
  </section>

</div>
```

O seletor `div > p` faz com que todos os filhos imediatos de `div` recebam regras de css. No exemplo seriam os `p` com  texto: Primeiro, Segundo, Terceiro.

Essas regras não se propagam aos `p` dentro de `section` pois esses não são mais filhos imediatos de `div`, mas sim "netos".

---

O seletor `p:first-child` diz que todos os `p` da página (independentemente de que pais tenham) que sejam o primeiro filho de um dado elemento, terão essas regras.

Repara que `Primeiro` e `Neto um` recebem essas regras, mas não `Bisneto dois` isto apesar de ser o primeiro `p` desse nível, mas é o segundo filho, não o primeiro.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta, Sergio!

Comment: @kidmalo ótimo que pude ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

**Immediate Child**

Seleciona o um elemento que seja filho **DIRETO** de outro elemento.

Por exemplo

```
div > span
```

Seleciona apenas o primeiro e o terceiro span que são filhos diretos.

```
    <div>
       <span>Essa é filha direta</span>
       <p>
          <span>Essa NÃO é filha direta.</span>
       </p>
       <span>Essa é filha direta</span>
    </div>
```

**First Child**

Seleciona todos os elementos do tipo que são **PRIMEIROS** filhos de outros elementos.

Por exemplo

```
p:first-child
```

Vai selecionar apenas os paragrafos que são primeiros filhos de outros elementos

```
<div>
   <p>Este sera selecionado</p>
   <p>Este NÃO sera selecionado</p>
</div>

<div>
   <h1>Este não é paragrafo</h1>
   <p>Este NÃO será selecionado</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta, Fabri!

Answer (score 1):

Simples, `Immediate Child` seleciona todos filhos correspondentes

`first-child` seleciona o primeiro filho correspondente

Seguindo seu exemplo se tiver apenas um elemento `p` não haverá diferença pois será o primeiro filho e filho imediato, mas caso tenha mais de um ai o `first-child` selecionara apenas o primeiro e o `Immediate Child` todos imediatos.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta, Lennon!